# axios returns "fullfilled" promise

Tags: reactjs, axios, return

Can someone please tell me why my Axios service function returns this:

The object looks fine in the service function.

```
Promise {<fulfilled>: {…}}
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Object
```

Here is the call:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setData(playlistService.getPlaylists);
  }, []);
  console.log(data);
```

And the function:

```
const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  withCredentials: true,
};

const getPlaylists = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`${API_SONGS_URL}/`, config);
    console.log('RES ', res);
    return res;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      return error.response.data;
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this could work

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPlayListAsync = async () => {
        const response = await playlistService.getPlaylists();
        setData(response)
    }
   fetchPlayListAsync()
}, []);
```

you can add appropriate checks of fetched data

Comment: Ah the request must also be waiting right .. of course .. thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome, glad I was able to help

Comment: Made my day actually :D